# How to include code that creates stored procedure in database script generated from model

Tags: sql-server, entity-framework

Is it even possible? I tried to update model from DB where I have my stored procedure, but it still does not help in what I want to get,i.e. call to create procedure in the output sql script.

Comment: See http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/19280/Stored-Procedure-Generator

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It appears that it is pretty much easy as one can add code that creates stored procedure in the 'tt' file as it is said here: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/data/gg558520.aspx